# Why crash if I release the NSIndexSet parameter passed to insertSections:withRowAnimation:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've wrote some code to batch delete/insert sections and cells from/into a table view. But I encountered a problem I can't understand. My codes are as follow

```
NSMutableArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
NSIndexSet *insertSections = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:kDeleteSection];
NSArray *insertDeleteIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:kDeleteSection], nil];

/// init deleteIndexPaths and insertIndexPaths

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView insertSections:insertSections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertDeleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

[insertSections release];
[deleteIndexPaths release];
//[insertSections release]; // If uncommented it, program will crash.
[insertDeleteIndexPaths release];
```

As the comment on the code, if I uncomment the statement **[insertSections release];**, the program will crash. Why? I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are releasing it twice:

```
**[insertSections release];**
[deleteIndexPaths release];
**//[insertSections release]; // If uncommented it, program will crash.**
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with the quick and simple answer that based on the code provided, you are creating an over-release situation. When you call `+alloc` on `NSIndexSet` at the top you implicitly assert ownership and will need an offsetting `-release` call. In the example provided, the commented out `-release` call is the second one and results in a message being sent to an instance that has been deallocated.

Comment: A slip of the pen. With XCode's tab automatically phrase expanding function, I mistake *insertIndexPaths* as *insertSections*.